# How to select rows within a table that are not in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, notin

I am having some bother in selecting books that are neither translated books, books series' nor book sections. The structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvuF7.png). (sorry, stackoverflow won't let me post an image with less than 10 reputation)

It uses [class inheritance design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/class-table-inheritance/info) with shared primary keys.

This is what I've came up with so far:

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM (
>         (
>             (`hedwig_db`.`refs` JOIN `hedwig_db`.`books` 
>                         ON `refs`.`ref_id`=`books`.`ref_id`
>             )
>         LEFT JOIN `hedwig_db`.`authors`
>                 ON `refs`.`ref_id` =  `authors`.`ref_id`
>         )
>     LEFT JOIN `hedwig_db`.`editors`
>             ON `books`.`book_id`=`editors`.`book_id`
>     )
> WHERE `books`.`book_id`
> NOT IN (SELECT `books`.`ref_id`,
>                 `books`.`book_id`,
>                 `book_section`.`book_id`,
>                 `book_translated`.`book_id`,
>                 `book_series`.`book_id`
>         FROM(
>                 (
>                     (`hedwig_db`.`books` JOIN `hedwig_db`.`book_translated`
>                         ON `books`.`book_id`=`book_translated`.`book_id`
>                     )
>                 JOIN `hedwig_db`.`book_section`
>                     ON `books`.`book_id`=`book_section`.`book_id`
>                 )
>             JOIN `hedwig_db`.`book_series`
>                 ON `books`.`book_id`=`book_series`.`book_id`
>             )
>     )
> ```

It's the NOT IN query that is returning nothing and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get what I'm looking for! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simplify the `where` clause to just use `not exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `hedwig_db`.`refs` r JOIN
     `hedwig_db`.`books` b 
     ON r.ref_id = b.ref_id LEFT JOIN
     `hedwig_db`.`authors` a
     ON r.ref_id =  a.ref_id LEFT JOIN
     `hedwig_db`.`editors` e
     ON b.book_id = e.book_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from `hedwig_db`.`book_translated` bt where bt.book_id = b.book_id) and
      NOT EXISTS (select 1 from `hedwig_db`.`series` bs where bs.book_id = b.book_id) and
      NOT EXISTS (select 1 from `hedwig_db`.`book_sections` bs where bs.book_id = b.book_id);
```

Your `not in` clause is joining the tables together, so it would be finding books that are all three.  You could do a `union all` instead, but I would stick with three different conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've just tried this out but the result set is the same as when the query `SELECT * FROM books JOIN authors ON ... JOIN editors ON ...` runs. Which means all books are selected rather than the books that are just books (i.e not translated, series nor section)

Comment: Ooops.  Those conditions should have been connected by `and` and not `or`.